# Change dimension of a span

Tags: html, css

I have a tooltip that looks like this

[image]

and my code looks like this

```
.calendar-tooltip:hover .calendar-tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}


<div class="my-template-cell">
          <span class="cal-day-number">{{ day.date | calendarDate:'monthViewDayNumber':locale }}</span>
      </div>
      <span *ngIf="isHoliday(day)" class="calendar-tooltiptext"> Vacation  </span>
      <span *ngIf="isNationalHoliday(day)" class="calendar-tooltiptext"> National Holiday </span>
```

What I need is that the height of tooltip changes if I have more text.
I have tried with height 60% but the 2nd row doesn't appear and with 100% is too big for a single row.

Comment: What if you give `height: auto` to the span?

Comment: or remove `height` altogether.

Comment: Are those populated like that or only on hover? If you're allowed to change it my opinion would be to have the text ellipse and then hover to get more details in a type of overlay.

Comment: Please paste a fiddle of your code so we can check and figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your tooltip text is given `height: 100%;` it will be that - not more and not less.

If you remove the height property as MrLister suggests, the text will grow beyond the bottom border (as long as you don't have `overflow: hidden;` on either of the parent elements).

I suggest using `min-height: 100%;` if you always want minimum full cell height.

Answer (score -2):

Like the comment add `height: auto`,  and try `min-height:60%;`